# How do I make iOS 7 Control Center behave like it does in Maps (small tab)?

Tags: ios, ios7, control-center

In Maps in iOS 7, if you swipe up from the bottom of the screen as if opening control center while the map view is full screen, you get a small tab instead of the full Control Center, and the map scrolls normally.  You then have to grab that tab and pull it up to open Control Center fully.  See this screenshot as an example:

[image]

I have an app with significant functionality triggered by dragging up on a small UI element at the bottom of the screen, and it's tricky to grab it in iOS 7 without swiping up from the bottom.  How do I trigger the same Control Center behavior in my app?  Is there a key in `Info.plist` that I can set?  Or is that some kind of private API that Apple uses?  It doesn't happen when the bottom toolbar is visible, so maybe it's some kind of state that can be set programmatically?

**UPDATE:** The same behavior occurs when you swipe down from the top of the screen as if to open Notification Center.

**UPDATE 2:** The camera app does the same thing, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088287/uiscreenedgepangesturerecognizer-conflicting-with-control-center) about `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to hide the status bar for the grabber to come up first. That being said, I think users would expect Control Center to come up when they drag up from the bottom of the screen, so I'd say preventing that from happening isn't a very good user experience.

Comment: This appears to work.  If the status bar is hidden, then you get the grabber the first time instead of the whole Notification Center or Control Center.